# How to determine the currently selected database in clickhouse

Tags: command-line-interface, clickhouse

How do you find which datatabse (i.e your current database name) was last selected with the `use <database>` command in clickhouse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need to use [currentDatabase](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql_reference/functions/other_functions/#currentdatabase)-function:

```sql
SELECT currentDatabase()
/*
┌─currentDatabase()─┐
│ default           │
└───────────────────┘
*/

use system;

SELECT currentDatabase()
/*
┌─currentDatabase()─┐
│ system            │
└───────────────────┘
*/
```

---

There are some issues related to this function:

[#6104: currentDatabase() + create table ON CLUSTER DDL](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/6104)

[issues in github ..](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/search?q=currentDatabase&type=Issues)